# Html helper link to nested resource Routes

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I have the following route:

```
$routes->resources('Articles', function ($routes) {
    $routes->resources('Comments');
});
```

I want to link to all comments of the article with id 4:

```
articles/4/comments
```

How can I create a link to this url with cakes HtmlHelper?

More about nested routes:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-nested-resource-routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the example route patterns given in the linked docs, the nested `Articles` > `Comments` resources will create routes for `Comments` with the following patterns:

```
/articles/:article_id/comments
/articles/:article_id/comments/:id
```

You can also check `$ bin/cake routes` to get a list of all connected routes with their patterns and defaults. The route you're looking for will be listed there as something like this:

```
+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route name     | URI template                   | Defaults                                                                 |
+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| comments:index | /articles/:article_id/comments | {"controller":"Comments","action":"index","_method":"GET","plugin":null} |
```

All resource routes are bound to specific HTTP methods (as can be seen above in the defaults column), ie internally the `_method` option is used, and the parent ID is prefixed with the singular controller/resource name.

To match the `Comments` index, simply target the `Comments` controller and `index` action as usual. Additionally pass the corresponding `_method` (for `index` that's `GET`), and pass the parent ID in a named fashion, ie as `article_id`, like:

```
[
    'controller' => 'Comments',
    'action' => 'index',
    '_method' => 'GET',
    'article_id' => 4
]
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Creating RESTful Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#resource-routes)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Generating URLs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls)**
- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Routes Shell](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/routes-shell.html)**

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution is so simple

Answer (score 0):

You could join Html and Url helpers, like this:

```
<?= 
    $this->Html->link(
        'Enter',
        $this->Url->build('/articles/4/comments', true),
        ['class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank']
    ); 
?>
```

**See also:**

- [Creating Links](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)
- [Generating URLs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html#generating-urls)